# Elastic Search to Get count of Individual Terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a elastic query using _count to get the count.

```
    {
      "query": {
         "bool": {
           "must": [ {
                "term": {
                          "A": "image"
                        }
                     }, 
                     {
                "aggs" : {
                        "C" : {
                                "terms" : { "field" : "C" ,
                                "include" : ["X:969", "Y:96"]
                                          }
                              }
                         }                   
                     }
                   ]
                 }
              }
    }
```

Now I get the output as expected .

```
{
  "count": 321,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 19,
    "successful": 19,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

But is there anyway to get the output like

```
  X:969 count 2
  Y:96  count 319
```

basically looking for individual counts rather than total count even when passed as array .

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count API is just a subset of the Search API, you need to use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get counts by fields. Probably it's not possible to use this aggregation in Count API, so you might consider running your queries against `_search`

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "C" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "C" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How do i pass array here "terms" : { "field" : "C" } as I tried passing it in [] but failed

Comment: please add new query as a part of the question?

Comment: Updated the Query